# Compare and validate input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to compare and validate my four fields in the following manner:

If somebody writes a client number in the field, there is no need to fill up the address fields. Likewise if somebody fills up the address fields they won't have to fill in the client number.

Here is my code:

```
$('#Form1').submit(function(event) {
    if ($(this).find('#address, #city, #postalcode, #customernum [input]').val() == '') {
        alert('Please enter Your client number or your address!')
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You need to use `.each()`. `.val()` only returns the value of the first element matching the selector, not all of them.

Comment: i only need to check specific fields, iv got 20 more fields.

Comment: i want to do either or if the address fields are empty enter the customer field and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#Form1').submit(function(event) {
    var formok = false;
    if ($("#customernum").val() != "") {
           formok = true;
    } else {
       formok = true;
       $("#address, #city, #postalcode").each(function () {
           if ($(this).val() == '') {
               formok = false;
               return false; // break out of loop
           }
       });
    }
    if (!formok) {
       alert('Please enter Your client number or your address!')
       event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your elements have an ID. Why use:

```
$(this).find(' #address, ...
```

? This is not necessary.

Try to do

```
$('#address, #city....
```

I've never used multiple selectors to do what you're trying to do, so I don't know if It'll works. I hope so though

Comment: Good information, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: Well, maybe that's just the problem. Jquery doesn't like that and It doesn't work. Not sure

Comment: Did you read my comment above about how `val()` works with a selector that matches multiple elements?

Comment: thanks again for your prompt help

Comment: @Barmar: Yep. each() is a nice help.
jheul: You're welcome